# How to make my loop check the if statement until the condition is met / basically until the button appears on screen?

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, while-loop, automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time



def runScript():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    playButton = '//*[@id="game-details-play-button-container"]/button'

    browser.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="right-navigation-header"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-username"]').send_keys("123")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-password"]').send_keys("abc")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-button"]').click()

    while True:
        if browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-full-width btn-common-play-game-lg btn-primary-md btn-min-width"):
            browser.find_element_by_xpath(playButton).click()
            break
        else:
            return False
    time.sleep(4)
```

How do I make my while loop statement loop through the statement until my if statement goes true?
I'm using Selenium by the way.

Comment: Remove the *else* and associated *return False*

Comment: Its still like that, I want my while true loop to keep checking the if statement forever or until the btn pops up, Please help me thank you :)

Comment: @Debunked please let me know if my solution clear and worked

Comment: @Prophet I seem to understand it and thanks, But There's this error when I tried to copy the one u sent me which says Unresolved reference 'By'

Comment: Please see if my updated answer resolved that?

Comment: Yooo It solved my problem I'm really crying full of joy right now, After asking too many programmers ur the only one that found the mistake, Thanks alot!!!! And also May I ask about the else statement, you made it into time.sleep() instead of returning the value?

Comment: First of all I'm happy I could help you. From your question I see you want to loop until the condition is met. So, in case the condition is fulfilled, the element exists you are clicking it and getting out. Otherwise I'm putting some delay and checking for the element presence again. In case you will use return false there it will not perform looping, it will click on element in case it found and return false otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Instead of `find_element_by_class_name` you can use `find_elements_by_class_name`. The difference is: if no such element found `find_element` will throw an exception while `find_elements` will return a **list** of web elements. In case there is a match, element exits, it will be non-empty list while non-empty list is interpreted by Python as Boolean `True`. Otherwise, in case no elements found it will return empty list
   interpreted as a Boolean `False`.
2. Since you are locating that element by several class names you should use XPath or CSS Selector, not `by_class_name`
3. Instead of `find_element_by_css_selector` you should use modern style of `find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value")`
   With all these and a correct indentation your code can be something like this:

```py
while True:
    if browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn-full-width.btn-common-play-game-lg.btn-primary-md.btn-min-width"):
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH,playButton).click()
        break
    else:         
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

You will need this import:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```